# What's are the differences between tensorflow_serving classification, predict and regression SignatureDefs

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I am trying to serve the tensorflow object detection api model in tensorflow serving, And I am confused by the 3 different SignatureDefs. What are the differences, When to choose one over another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow Serving uses a different way of updating models weights and different signature mechanism is used in serving. In order to save model in serving se uses SavedModel. SavedModel provides a language-neutral format to save machine-learned models that is recoverable and hermetic. It enables higher-level systems and tools to produce, consume and transform TensorFlow models.

This support SignatureDefs 
Graphs that are used for inference tasks typically have a set of inputs and outputs. This is called a Signature.
SavedModel uses SignatureDefs to allow generic support for signatures that may need to be saved with the graphs.

For those who previously used TF-Exporter/SessionBundle, Signatures in TF-Exporter will be replaced by SignatureDefs in SavedModel.

A SignatureDef requires specification of:
inputs as a map of string to TensorInfo.
outputs as a map of string to TensorInfo.
method_name (which corresponds to a supported method name in the loading tool/system).

Classification SignatureDefs support structured calls to TensorFlow Serving's Classification API. These prescribe that there must be an inputs Tensor, and that there are two optional output Tensors: classes and scores, at least one of which must be present.

Predict SignatureDefs support calls to TensorFlow Serving's Predict API. These signatures allow you to flexibly support arbitrarily many input and output Tensors. For the example below, the signature my_prediction_signature has a single logical input Tensor images that are mapped to the actual Tensor in your graph x:0.

Regression SignatureDefs support structured calls to TensorFlow Serving's Regression API. These prescribe that there must be exactly one inputs Tensor, and one outputs Tensor.

Please refer:

https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/signature_defs

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/599

The Classify API is higher-level and more specific than the Predict API. Classify accepts tensorflow.serving.Input (which wraps a list of tf.Examples) as input and produces classes and scores as output. It is used for classification problems. Predict, on the other than, accepts tensors as input and outputs tensors. It can be used for regression, classification and other types of inference problems.